# I can't understand why HIWORD macro uses &0xFFFF mask?

Tags: c, winapi

Taken from Charles Petzold book:

> ```
> case WM_SIZE:
>  cxClient = LOWORD (lParam) ;
>  cyClient = HIWORD (lParam) ;
>  return 0 ;
> ```
>
> You'll see code like this in virtually every Windows program. LOWORD
>   and HIWORD are macros that are defined in the Windows header file
>   `WINDEF.H`. If you're curious, the definitions of these macros look
>   like this
>
> ```
> #define LOWORD(l) ((WORD)(l))
> #define HIWORD(l) ((WORD)(((DWORD)(l) >> 16) & 0xFFFF))
> ```
>
> The two macros return WORD values that is, 16−bit unsigned

I would only use the shift operator in the HIWORD definition.
Like this:

```
#define HIWORD(l) ((WORD)(((DWORD)(l) >> 16))
```

Why is he masking that value?

Could someone explain this to me bitwise?

Edit:

```
HIWORD(l) ((WORD)(((DWORD)(l) >> 16) & 0xFFFF))


l=0x11223344
((DWORD)(l) >> 16) l becomes 0x00001122
(((DWORD)(l) >> 16) & 0xFFFF))
```

what is happening here to l?

Comment: Perhaps this dates from a time where integer conversion rules weren't standardised

Comment: The book was written in 1998(Programming Windows 5th Edition), I have the 2002 version.

Comment: The book is the same book that we all learnt Windows on, originally published in 1988. In any case, Petzold doesn't write the Windows header files. These macros date from the dawn of time.

Comment: What I can't understand is why it stll works!!! using &0xFFFF should zero out the 16bits we just shifted to the right.I'll edit my post to explain my question better

Comment: I do not know the actual definitions of WORD and DWORD, but think about what would happen when `l` has more than 32 bits. If you dont mask the result, you might have a value that is greater than `2^16-1`. BTW, in response to your above comment: 0xFFFF will **retain** the bits that were shifted right by 16 places, and zero out everything before it.

Comment: You got that wrong strax, it will not zero the ones you just pushed right. It will zero out the new numbers pushed into the number from the left. It will keep the 16 bits you just pushed down.

Comment: @Thrustmaster Yes, but unsigned conversion rules will have the same effect. So the cast to `WORD` has the same effect, for a standards compliant compiler.

Comment: @strax I guess your question is not really about these macros, it's more about the fact that you don't really understand these bitwise operations yet. And so discussions about standards compliant compilers and unsigned conversions are probably not at the level of which you need help. What text book are you using to learn C?

Comment: Kernighan and Ritchie ansi c

Comment: I'm sure that text covers bitwise operations. I guess a refresher there will help. This is an interesting question from the perspective that `& 0xffff` is not needed in my view since the conversion to `WORD` does the exact same thing.

Comment: The trancation confused me when i tried to translate what the mask did since all the experiments came as expected in VS even though my logic was off.The answer to my question is covered by Iggy but McNubb went 2 levels deeper.I don't know how to lock this correctly.I can't have 2 correct answers :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess your point is that because `WORD` is guaranteed to be 16 bit, then `(WORD)(x >> 16)` can only be 16 bits anyway, therefore the mask is useless.

Or perhaps that because `DWORD` is guaranteed to be 32 bit unsigned, then `(x >> 16)` is guaranteed to not have any bits set other than the lower 16.

In the early days , it was intended that `WORD` would match the system's CPU word size (i.e. `int`).  However it turned out that so much unportable code was written that it would have broken too many things to make `WORD` 32-bit and `DWORD` 64-bit when Win32 came out.

Perhaps this macro was never updated. However we can certainly say that the `& 0xFFFF` cannot possibly cause a problem, so there is no reason to remove it. (Don't fix what ain't broke!)

Perhaps it is even a good idea to keep it, just in case `WORD` is ever increased.

Comment: The latest versions of the header file cast to `DWORD_PTR`, FWIW

Comment: @DavidHeffernan what do they say exactly?

Comment: `#define LOWORD(l)           ((WORD)(((DWORD_PTR)(l)) & 0xffff))
#define HIWORD(l)           ((WORD)((((DWORD_PTR)(l)) >> 16) & 0xffff))
`

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm struggling to see why they didn't just stick with the original, it doesn't seem to make a difference

Comment: Well, the `& 0xffff` could be removed also, assuming standards compliant unsigned integer conversion and the integer type sizes that are supported.

Answer (score 1):

In 32  bit register hiword is on left side(16)bits, 
Loword is on right side(16)bits
LOWORD(l) (WORD)(l)&0XFFFF
It means 0XFFFF mask returns the value of
right side of register.
HIWORD(l) (WORD)(l)>>16)&0XFFFF
This shifts 32 bit value to the right 16 places
or bits.so we have a word on right side, now
0XFFFF mask is anded, that gives us HIWORD
Hope this answer is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is some old compiler would complain (produce a warning during compile) about possible truncation if the & 0xFFFF wasn't used, even though it's not needed as pointed out elsewhere in this thread.

Answer (score -1):

```
& 0xFFFF
```

It make sure the 16first bits will be ignored

```
0x12345678 & 0x0000FFFF == 0x00005678
```

The shifting doesn't ensure you'll be left with zeroes (try shifting -1), thus they use a bitwise and to ensure this.

Comment: The cast to `WORD` will also ensure that the first 16 bits are ignored. So one wonders why that needs to be done twice. Do you know?

Comment: Nope, that makes your answer worse. All the types here are unsigned. Do you know the rules for unsigned conversion?

Comment: Sorry I guess I answered a bit too fast then. I see no other reason why doing this twice is necessary, unless you want to be compatible with exotic compilers